# Как убрать папки с под гита?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-add

Здравствуйте.
Установил гит, и у меня на ветке мастер все мои папки с пк.Как убрать из под гита их подскажите пожалуйста

```
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .bash_history
        AppData/
        Contacts/
        Desktop/
        Documents/
        Downloads/
        Favorites/
        IdeaProjects/
        Links/
        Music/
        NTUSER.DAT
        NTUSER.DAT{39b0c0d2-7aed-11e6-af82-967153cd1394}.TxR.0.regtrans-ms
        NTUSER.DAT{39b0c0d2-7aed-11e6-af82-967153cd1394}.TxR.1.regtrans-ms
        NTUSER.DAT{39b0c0d2-7aed-11e6-af82-967153cd1394}.TxR.2.regtrans-ms
        NTUSER.DAT{39b0c0d2-7aed-11e6-af82-967153cd1394}.TxR.blf
        NTUSER.DAT{39b0c0d3-7aed-11e6-af82-967153cd1394}.TM.blf
        NTUSER.DAT{39b0c0d3-7aed-11e6-af82-967153cd1394}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms
        NTUSER.DAT{39b0c0d3-7aed-11e6-af82-967153cd1394}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms
        OneDrive/
        Pictures/
        Saved Games/
        Searches/
        Tracing/
        Videos/
        YandexDisk/
        ntuser.dat.LOG1
        ntuser.dat.LOG2
```

Comment: Простое решение - создавать репозиторий в отдельной папке, а не в домашней папке пользователя (т.е. создать папку, перейти в нее, в ней выполнить `git init`).

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 3):

Судя по `Untracked files` в выдаче, файлы и папки ещё не под git: git'ом предлагается использовать `git add`, чтобы добавить их туда. А раз они не добавлены, то и проблемы нет.

Есть два пути

1. Случайно был создан репозиторий git в ненужной папке. Если все файлы и папки не были закоммичены и есть необходимость избавиться от этого локального репозитория, то попробуйте удалить скрытую папку `.git`, должна располагаться в том же каталоге, что и перечисленные в тексте вопроса папки.
2. Если репозиторий в этом месте нужен, а многие папки -- нет, то внесите их в файл `.gitignore`. Создайте файл `.gitignore` в том же каталоге с содержимым, например

   ```
   AppData/
   Contacts/
   Desktop/
   Documents/
   Downloads/
   Favorites/
   IdeaProjects/
   Links/
   Music/
   *.pdf
   NTUSER.DAT*
   ```

Comment: Зачем удалять? Просто перенести в отдельный каталог, и потом `git reset --hard`, а вот файлы рабочего каталога действительно надо чистить, но в этом легко поможет `git ls-files`.